# Array Formula in just one cell

Tags: list, if-statement, google-sheets, arraylist

I have a formula that do almost what I need. I'm trying to get a list of values with a condition depending about one value, is objetive 1 is equal or over to 80 show me the list of objetives equal or over 80. My formula is this one:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(('Product Prioritization Matrix'!C7:C >= 80), 'Product Prioritization Matrix'!B7:B,""))
```

My problem comes when I try to put this in just one cell in the last image will show what I need visualy.

The next images will show the sheets:

[image]

My formula

[image]

Expected result

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think a JOIN(... , FILTER(  structure will work for this:

```
=JOIN(", ",FILTER(Sheet1!B:B,Sheet1!C:C>=80))
```